# How to Convert WGS84 to lat long in delphi7

Tags: delphi, gps, wgs84

I want to WGS84 coord values convert to lat long in Delphi7, how to make?

Thanks.

---

I received WGS84 format coord from gps device (comport) but need to projection (for map) lat long, i am received this coord :

> $GPGNS,080219.00,4054.34347,N,02916.99092,E,AN,11,0.89,134.1‌​,37.7,,*7B Map Lat : 40.9057 Map Long : 29.2831

Comment: I think you need to define the problem more precisely.

Comment: i received WGS84 format coord from gps device (comport) but need to projection (for map) lat long, i am received this coord : 


$GPGNS,080219.00,4054.34347,N,02916.99092,E,AN,11,0.89,134.1,37.7,,*7B



Map Lat : 40.9057
Map Long : 29.2831

Comment: This format is called NMEA and is pretty well documented, e.g. here http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

Answer (score 1):

The 'GNS' message is described e.g. [here](https://www.trimble.com/OEM_ReceiverHelp/V4.44/en/NMEA-0183messages_GNS.html)

From your message we can extract

> 4054.34347,N, = latitude
>
> 02916.99092,E, = longitude

**Latitude:**

The **two** first digits (padded with 0's if needed) of the latitude (40 in your sample) are degrees.
The rest (54.34347) are minutes.
The 'N' is northern hemisphere ('S' would be southern).

Conversion to float as double would be

```
function TGpsMsg.LatStrToDouble(Lat: string; NS: char): double;
begin
  result := StrToFloat(LeftStr(Lat, 2));
  result := result + StrToFloat(MidStr(Lat, 3, 8))/60;
  if (NS = 'S') or (NS = 's') then
    result := -result;
end;
```

Your sample is 40.9057245 N

**Longitude:**

The **three** first digits (padded with 0's if needed) of the longitude (029) are degrees.
The rest (16.99092) are minutes.
The 'E' is east of the 0-meridian (Greenwich) ('W' would be west).

```
function TGpsMsg.LngStrToDouble(Lng: string; EW: char): double;
begin
  result := StrToFloat(LeftStr(Lng, 3));
  result := result + StrToFloat(MidStr(Lng, 4, 8))/60;
  if (EW = 'W') or (EW = 'w') then
    result := -result;
end;
```

Your sample is 29.283182 E

Comment: it's worked! thank you Tom.